# Square Image View on RecyclerView Item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I would like to have a square ImageView to the left of my `recyclerView`.

How do we achieve this? I am hoping for a solution that is not hard coded.

Any idea please?
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImageView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:text="Username"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rankProfileImageView"/>

</RelativeLayout>>
```

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal I believe that both `wrap_content` and `match_parent` could not do it

Comment: i think your image is round shape with transparent back .... normally your code looks like ok..

Comment: @Tanimreja i need a same height and width on the image regardless of the size

Comment: is your image loading from drawable or sd card ?

Comment: You should hard code the width and height. Try with 48dp

Answer (score 0):

Use below library to display image in circluar View:

https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview